# Java - Overriding StdOut and writing Japanese to a File

Tags: java, character-encoding, save, stdout, streamwriter

I have been trying to create a class that can be set as Standard Out and that writes to a File. So far, no problem. However, when I try to write some Japanese into the output it won't show up in the files. All I get are lines of '?' characters.

This is how my OutputStream class looks like (I create an instance of it and hands that over to "System.setOut(OutputStream)" in my main method).

```
public class MyStdOutStream extends OutputStream {
    private OutputStreamWriter out;

    public MyStdOutStream(File file) throws IOException {
        out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        super.close();   //No idea if this line does anything...
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int nr) throws IOException {
        out.write(nr);
    }
}
```

I then accept input through a JTextField (while testing, it will be a different source later), and print that both with "System.out.println(String)" and also appending it to a JTextArea. It shows up as proper Japanese in the JTextArea, but not in the File.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I have tested with **all** available Charsets in the StandardCharsets import without success.

**EDIT:** It is an assignment, and I am not allowed to use anything other than the Standard Java Library (so, no imported JARs)

Comment: Is it part of a course? If not, there is many logging frameworks, like log4j that does it

Comment: It is part of an assignment, yes. I cannot use anything other than the Java Standard Library.

Comment: Isn't this question a duplicate of your question [Java - Get Japanese from JTextField and save to File](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53810121/2985643)? If so, please delete this question. If not, can you clarify how this question differs from your other one?

Comment: @skomisa That other question I solved by calling the String.getBytes method while providing the UTF-16 Charset, and then saving the bytes to a File. That method does not work when overriding the StdOut since in that case any printout goes through the "write(int i)" method, meaning it already converted to an integer without me having any chance to specify which Charset to use. That would be the difference between the questions.

Comment: @AnjuMaaka OK. Are you saying that the output file contains invalid characters, or that when you render the content of that file the characters in it are displayed as  **?** characters. If it is the former you need to provide some sample input data for the Japanese characters, and the resulting hex content in the file. If it is the latter, then what font is being used when displaying the file's content, and how are you displaying the file's content? Also, although it's not relevant to your problem, why did you choose to override the **close()** method?

Comment: Well, as for the main question; the problem was solved by using "UTF-16" instead of "UTF-8" as I used here. And about overriding the *close()* that was just so that I could flush/close the OutputStream (since it is NOT the same stream as the class itself). It was just so that both the "MyStdOutStream" and the "OutputStreamWriter" INSIDE of that class could be closed at the same time.