# Java - Get Japanese from JTextField and save to File

Tags: java, file, io, fileoutputstream, corrupt-data

I am trying to get Japanese input from a `JTextField` (with the `getText()` method) and saving that to a File. I am confident that it does get Japanese format from the `JTextField` since I can `append()` that `String` to a `JTextArea` and it will be in the correct Japanese Format.

However, when I try to write to a File it only turns to gibberish! I have tried to use an `OutputStreamWriter` instantiated with `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` and I have tried with a plain `FileOutputStream` where I send in the bytes from calling `getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` on the String. In both cases the resulting file looks more like the following:

```
æ—¥æœ¬èªžã�¯é›£ã�—ã�„ã�¨æ€�ã�†ï¼�å­¦ã�³ã�Ÿã�„ã�ªã‚‰ã€�æ—¥æœ¬ã�§ä½�ã‚€
```

Which is not what I want, naturally. Does anyone have any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: japanese char are not fully part of UTF-8 std they are encode in UTF-16 try change your char set and make sur that what your using to read the file support ths format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you are creating the file with ISO-8859-1 instead UTF-8. 
I'm also inferring you are using Eclipse because your previous questions.

## Change your workspace settings

Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace : UTF-8

[image]

## Default encoding for all content types

[image]

### TestClass

This is the class i used to test the theory

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            File fileDir = new File("test.txt");
            String japanese = "路権ち点節ヤトツ限聞ド勇売質タカア";
            Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileDir)));
            out.append(japanese);
            System.out.println(japanese);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
    }
}
```

### Input/output with different settings

OutputFileISO: `è·¯æ¨©ã¡ç¹ç¯ã¤ããéèãåå£²è³ªã¿ã«ã¢`

OutputFileUTF8: `路権ち点節ヤトツ限聞ド勇売質タカア`